# Struts2 ognl execute request method

Tags: methods, struts2, request, execute, ognl

I'm trying to use OGNL to evaluate if the session is valid, in order to show some information. For that I've the following JSP

```
[...]
<s:if test="request.isRequestedSessionValid()">
[...] (show user name, etc)
</s:if>
```

But it doesn't work. I've also tried "#request.isRequestedSessionValid()","%{request.isRequestedSessionValid()}" and "{request.isRequestedSessionValid()}", but I always get an error message target java.lang.NullPointerException: target is null for method isRequestedSessionValid or [OgnlValueStack] Could not find method [#request.isRequestedSessionValid()]. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, now that I've had a chance to look deeper into this I am tossing out my old answer. `#request` won't work because that is basically the equivalent of the JSP EL expression `${requestScope.requestedSessionIdValid}`, but that property isn't a request scope property, its an actual property of the `HttpServletRequest`.

You can do this easily with JSP EL using:

```
<c:if test="${pageContext.request.requestedSessionIdValid}">
    ...
</c:if>
```

I don't know that there is an equally concise way to get at this with OGNL.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I tried "%{#request.requestedSessionIdValid}", "%{#request.isRequestedSessionIdValid}" and "%{#request.isRequestedSessionIdValid()}", but nothing worked. The last one gave me this exception "[OgnlValueStack] Could not find method [#request.isRequestedSessionIdValid()]", which I don't understand. The request has that method, so why it's not picking it?